# If $A>0$ is symmetric and has exactly one positive eigenvalue, then $a_{ij} \ge \sqrt {a_{ii}a_{jj}} \ge \min\{a_{ii},a_{jj}\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let that $A\in M_n$

- $A>0$ (all $a_{ij}>0$).
- $A$ is symmetric.
- $A$ has exactly one positive eigenvalue.

Why does $a_{ij} \ge \sqrt {a_{ii}a_{jj}} \ge \min\{a_{ii},a_{jj}\}$?

for all $i,j=1,2,....,n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$A$ has eigenvalues
$$\lambda_1 \le \lambda_2 \le \ldots \le \lambda_n$$
and the smallest $(n-1)$ of them are $\le 0$. Using the Cauchy [interlacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem) theorem we have that the smallest eigenvalue of any principal $2\times 2$ matrix of $A$ is $\le \lambda_{n-1} \le 0$. That implies that the determinant of such a matrix is $\le 0$ ( since the diagonal elements are $>0$)